# AWS CDK Init Container dependency with Fargate Pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I'm trying to use the CDK to define a `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` like this:

```js
const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, 'Cluster', { vpc });
const loadBalancedService = new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, "FargateService", {
      cluster,
      taskImageOptions: {
        image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry("public.ecr.aws/XXXXXXXX/my-node-app:latest"),
        environment: {
          DATABASE_HOST: rdsCluster.attrEndpointAddress,
          DATABASE_NAME: databaseName,
          DATABASE_USERNAME: databaseCredentialsSecret.secretValueFromJson('username').toString(),
          DATABASE_PASSWORD: databaseCredentialsSecret.secretValueFromJson('password').toString(),
        }
      },
    });
```

I already have an RDS cluster created earlier in the app.  I want to run an init container before bringing up this Fargate Service but I'm not quite sure how.  I know there is a `ContainerDependency` in the aws-ecs construct but I don't think I can apply it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECS Containers [can have dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDependency.html). In the CDK, you can add a dependency to a `ContainerDefinition` construct using its [addContainerDependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.ContainerDefinition.html#addwbrcontainerwbrdependenciescontainerdependencies) method.

As you are using the L3 `ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` construct, your first step is getting a reference to the underlying service's `ContainerDefinition` via the task definition's [defaultContainer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.FargateTaskDefinition.html#defaultcontainer) property:

```js
const serviceContainer: : ecs.ContainerDefinition | undefined = loadBalancedService.taskDefinition.defaultContainer;
if (!serviceContainer) throw new Error('LB Service default container must be defined!');
```

Then add the `init` Container to the task definition:

```js
const initContainer = loadBalancedService.taskDefinition.addContainer('init', {
  image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('init/my-image'),
  essential: false,
});
```

Finally, create the dependency with a `SUCCESS` condition.  This [condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.ContainerDependencyCondition.html) validates that a dependent container runs to completion (and exits with 0) before permitting other containers to start:

```js
serviceContainer.addContainerDependencies({
  container: initContainer,
  condition: ecs.ContainerDependencyCondition.SUCCESS,
});
```